# How to obtain a random weighted directed graph?

Tags: networkx, sage

I'm looking for a way to get an adjacency list representation of a random, weighted directed graph. The weights between edges should be bounded integer values chosen at random uniformly.

Something similar to [`RandomGNM()`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_generators.html#sage.graphs.graph_generators.GraphGenerators.RandomGNM) but for directed graphs.

Comment: There are several ways you might do that.   Can you post some code for what you have tried?